# Is there a difference between the -cp and -classpath options?

Tags: java, linux, classpath

When I'm using `-classpath` in example 1 to execute my java application from another directory, it shows error unsatisfied link error. such as

```
error: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no <java main classname> in java.library.path
```

example1:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -classpath ".:<.jar files path>:</java application directory/>" <java main class name>
```

But when I run example2 command in any random directory in the `/home/root/`,
it is running my java application.

example2:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -cp ".:<.jar files path>:</java application directory/>" <java main class name>
```

hence I just want to what is the difference between `-classpath` and `-cp`.

My code example

```
class enGraph{
static {

        /*
         * Load native library libepdgraph.so (Unixes) at runtime This library contains
         * a native method called button()
         */
        File lib = new File("/home/root/" + System.mapLibraryName("enGraph"));
        System.load(lib.getAbsolutePath());


    }
}
```

Comment: Are both commands run from the same directory? In other words, are you positive `-cp` vs `-classpath` is the *only* difference? Because those two options, according to the manual, are exact synonyms. And why are you also setting `java.library.path`?

Comment: The reality is that `-cp` and `-classpath` have exactly the same effect.  The difference you are seeing is due to something else.

Comment: @StephenC I'm not sure I agree with the closure as duplicate with that specific target. It doesn't answer the question of why one command works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the question that has been asked, is what is the difference, which is a duplicate. The example, on the other hand, is not reproducible at all. Java will never search the main class on the library path.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - Well, 1) that is unanswerable based on the information given to us, and 2) it wasn't what the OP actually asked.  He clearly just asks (twice!) what is the difference between the two variants of the option.  If he actually wants an answer to the question you are *inferring* ... the OP needs to provide more information.   (And, ideally *real* information rather than a made up example; see Holger's comment!)